# Trouble with installing new ADT Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I'm trying to update my ADT to new version 23 so I found guides like this to perform the update:

> 1. Got to "Help > Install New Software"
> 2. List item
> 3. Click on "What is already installed?"
>      Remove any existing components that you wish to replace/update.
>      Once done, either install the new updated via the ADT url or download the zip and install from that .

But when I click on "What is already installed?" and try to unistall version 22 of ADT I get this error:

[image]

I'm really confused! Details say it cant remove eclipse.exe but if it remove it then my whole eclipse goes! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not installing Android Studio and importing your projects there?

Comment: @AlexP Honestly I have downloaded latest Android Studio but I'm not sure about using it I searched a little and people say it's early to use AS because it's not stable yet I dont know is it time to migrate to AS now?

Comment: Personally I like it more, and currently didn't find any major glitches. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem so describe here what I did maybe it save someone else!

1- to get rid of this error

- disable your antivirus protection
- make sure that your os user has full permisions for writing and deleting files
- be sure your eclipse folder is in c:\
- run eclipse as administrator

2- after this you can use the instructions I mentioned at my question to install newer version of ADT but remember don't restart eclipse after unistalling older version! even if eclipse says you must restart to changes take effect don't do that! it simply removes eclipse.exe so you don't have any exe file to start your eclipse again! So `without restarting eclipse` after unistalling older version of ADT plugin use ADT url and install newer version.

3- enjoy!